# CSS selector : element who has a specific parent?

Tags: css

http://plnkr.co/edit/rO1cev9Pw7TNbeGLioVk?p=preview

How can I set

```
margin-left:4px
```

to all checkboxes whose parent(not immediate parent, but any) has a class dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain selectors. This here should work perfectly fine:

```
.dropdown input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following construct:

```
.dropdown input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Check out the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent Class name `.dropdown` and set

```
.dropdown input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MSsVjlFRuR3xLVh7HrPx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```